# SQL Server filtering

Tags: sql

A new government reporting regulation requires you to develop a query that can count the number of male dependents of employees of the company. The information is stored in the `dep_gender` column of the `dependent` table. The result table should have a single output column labeled `Number Male Dependents`.

**So for this part I have :**

```
SELECT COUNT(DEP_GENDER)"Number of Male Dependents"
FROM dependent
where dep_gender = 'M';
```

which works just fine now to 'revise' for the next part.. I am having some problems because I cannot figure out how to filter into two different groups with associated counts for males and females.

A revision to the government reporting regulation requires the report to count the number of male and female dependents of the company. Display the information as two columns, one for gender and one for the associated count. The result table should have two rows, one for each gender. Use a single query. Additionally, the gender output column should be formatted as `CHAR(6)` and have a heading label of `Gender`. The count column should have a heading label of `Number Counted`.

Comment: Wow is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a `Group By` query:

```
Select Cast(Dep_Gender as Char(6)) as Gender,
    Count(1) 'Number Counted'
From Dependent
Group By Cast(Dep_Gender as Char(6))
```

`Cast` is used  since the requirements (homework perhaps) are to format the gender as a char(6).

Comment: If this answered your question, please consider accepting this answer so that sgeddes can get the reputation credit for it.

Comment: @user2203516 -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Male' As [Gender], COUNT(DEP_GENDER) AS [Counted]
FROM dependent
where dep_gender = 'M'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Female', COUNT(DEP_GENDER)
FROM dependent
where dep_gender = 'F'
```

Comment: No reason to have two separate database scans when a single scan with `GROUP BY` will do the job.